# Out of memory error - Error Code: 2008 MySQL client ran out of memory

Tags: mysql, union

I was trying to run the below query inside either mySQL workbench or dbForge, or even asp.net website, however I am always getting "out of memory exception".

The database is huge, and there are a lot of records need to be returned. I have read through some of the other questions that I need to slicing down the query to use less memory, but this is a UNION JOIN with 2 simple select statements, from 3 different tables. How can I possible to reduce this?

```
SELECT
    t.TICKET as 'Ticket',       
        t.LOGIN as 'Login Id',
        u.Name,
        t.OPEN_Time as 'Open Time',
        (CASE WHEN t.CLOSE_Time>@CONST_EMPTY_DATE THEN t.CLOSE_time ELSE NULL END) as 'Close Time/Liquidation Time',
        (CASE WHEN t.CMD=@CMD_OP_BUY then 'Buy' ELSE 'Sell' END) as 'Type/Liquidation Action',
        t.SYMBOL as 'Symbol',
        t.VOLUME/100.0 as 'Volume',
        t.OPEN_PRICE as 'Open Price',
        t.SL as 'S/L',
        t.TP as 'T/P',
        t.CLOSE_PRICE as 'Closed Price',
        t.SWAPS as 'Swap',
    (t.VOLUME/100.0)*lots.`Lot Size`*t.OPEN_PRICE as 'Open amount of money',        
    (t.VOLUME/100.0)*lots.`Lot Size`* t.CLOSE_PRICE as 'Closed amount of money', 
    t.PROFIT as 'Profit',
    t.COMMISSION as 'Commission',
      (CASE
          WHEN u.GROUP like '%USD%' THEN 'USD'
          WHEN u.GROUP like '%EUR%' THEN 'EUR'
          WHEN u.GROUP like '%JPY%' THEN 'JPY'
          WHEN u.GROUP like '%GBP%' THEN 'GBP'
          ELSE '???' END) as 'Currency',
    t.SERVER_ID as 'server ID'
    FROM 
        trades t 
        INNER JOIN users u ON t.LOGIN=u.LOGIN 
    AND t.SERVER_ID = u.SERVER_ID
        and t.CMD IN (@CMD_OP_BUY,@CMD_OP_SELL) 
        #and t.CLOSE_TIME between fromdate and todate 
        #and u.LOGIN = inlogin 
    and t.HISTORY = 'N'
    inner join lotsize lots on t.SYMBOL = lots.Name
  where t.close_time > '2012-09--17 00:00:00' and t.close_time < '2012-09-24 00:00:00'
UNION ALL
  Select 
    Null as 'Ticket',
        l.LOGIN as 'Login Id',
        u.Name,
        Null as 'Open Time',
        l.liquidation_timestamp as 'Close Time/Liquidation Time',
        l.liquidation_action as 'Type/Liquidation Action',
        Null as 'Symbol',
        Null as 'Volume',
        Null as 'Open Price',
        Null as 'S/L',
        Null as 'T/P',
        Null as 'Closed Price',
        Null as 'Swap',
    Null as 'Open amount of money',     
    Null as 'Closed amount of money', 
    Null as 'Profit',
    Null as 'Commission',
      (CASE
          WHEN u.GROUP like '%USD%' THEN 'USD'
          WHEN u.GROUP like '%EUR%' THEN 'EUR'
          WHEN u.GROUP like '%JPY%' THEN 'JPY'
          WHEN u.GROUP like '%GBP%' THEN 'GBP'
          ELSE '???' END) as 'Currency',
    l.SERVER_ID as 'MT4 server ID'
  From liquidations as l 
    INNER JOIN users as u ON l.LOGIN=u.LOGIN
    AND l.SERVER_ID = u.SERVER_ID;
```

I think I need to mention that if I run either of the select query seperatly, then it will give me the correct results. It is just when using the UNION to join them together, I am getting the out of memory error.

Trade table

```
'mt4_trades', 'CREATE TABLE `mt4_trades` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `TICKET` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LOGIN` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SYMBOL` char(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DIGITS` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CMD` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VOLUME` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OPEN_TIME` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `OPEN_PRICE` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `SL` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `TP` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `CLOSE_TIME` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `EXPIRATION` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `CONV_RATE1` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `CONV_RATE2` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `CONV_RATE3` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `COMMISSION` decimal(18,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `COMMISSION_AGENT` decimal(18,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SWAPS` decimal(18,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CLOSE_PRICE` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `PROFIT` decimal(18,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TAXES` decimal(18,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `COMMENT` char(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INTERNAL_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MARGIN_RATE` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `TIMESTAMP` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MODIFY_TIME` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `MODIFY_REASON` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `HISTORY` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BALANCE` decimal(18,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MT4_SERVER_ID` varchar(30) DEFAULT '''',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `mt4_trades_ticket_history_server_id_i` (`TICKET`,`HISTORY`,`MT4_SERVER_ID`),
  KEY `mt4_trades_login_server_id_history_i` (`LOGIN`,`MT4_SERVER_ID`,`HISTORY`),
  KEY `mt4_cmd_i` (`CMD`),
  KEY `mt4_open_time_i` (`OPEN_TIME`),
  KEY `mt4_close_time_i` (`CLOSE_TIME`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16427471 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'
```

User table

```
'mt4_users', 'CREATE TABLE `mt4_users` (
  `MODIFY_TIME` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `LOGIN` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''0'',
  `USER_GROUP` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BALANCE` decimal(18,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PREVMONTHBALANCE` decimal(18,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PREVBALANCE` decimal(18,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PREVMONTHEQUITY` decimal(18,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PREVEQUITY` decimal(18,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BALANCE_STATUS` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EQUITY` decimal(18,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MARGIN` decimal(18,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MARGIN_LEVEL` decimal(18,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MARGIN_FREE` decimal(18,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CREDIT` decimal(18,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MODIFY_REASON` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NAME` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EMAIL` varchar(48) DEFAULT NULL,
  `COMMENT` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MT4_SERVER_ID` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '''',
  `GROUP` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ADDRESS` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`LOGIN`,`MT4_SERVER_ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `mt4_users_uk` (`GROUP`,`LOGIN`,`MT4_SERVER_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'
```

Liquidation table

```
'mt4_liquidations', 'CREATE TABLE `mt4_liquidations` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `LOGIN` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LIQUIDATION_ACTION` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LIQUIDATION_TIMESTAMP` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `EQUITY_BEFORE_LIQUIDATION` decimal(18,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MARGIN_BEFORE_LIQUIDATION` decimal(18,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BALANCE_BEFORE_LIQUIDATION` decimal(18,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MT4_SERVER_ID` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '''',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`,`MT4_SERVER_ID`),
  KEY `Login` (`LOGIN`),
  KEY `liquidation_timestamp` (`LOGIN`,`LIQUIDATION_TIMESTAMP`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10526248 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'
```

Output of the explain query

```
'1', 'PRIMARY', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables'
'2', 'UNION', 'l', 'ALL', 'Login,liquidation_timestamp', NULL, NULL, NULL, '10502418', ''
'2', 'UNION', 'u', 'eq_ref', 'PRIMARY', 'PRIMARY', '96', 'l.LOGIN,l.MT4_SERVER_ID', '1', ''
NULL, 'UNION RESULT', '<union1,2>', 'ALL', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, ''
```

Comment: Try to use paginal mode in dbForge Studio. In paginal mode you can set a number of rows on the page to display the data in parts. To switch paginal mode on press the Paginal Mode button and set Page Row Count.

Comment: What are your table schemas? (the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table`) What is the the output of `EXPLAIN your_query`?

Comment: @Devart, thank you for the comment, I use dbForge just for testing and some dev work before putting the code onto the webpage, which is written in ASP.net. I am getting out of memory error from both places, plus mysql workbench also.

Comment: @Jocelyn, I have the output of all 3 tables, but not sure what I should look at? Do you want me to post those codes here?

Comment: @Jocelyn, forgot to mention that those tables were not created by me, they were given to me to query.

Comment: @Will Click the "edit" link below the question, and add the output of the queries to your question.

Comment: @Jocelyn, I have added the output of those 2 queries. I noticed there is something about the where clause, is this causing the query to crash? I added the where clause cos I needed a date range, inside the website, where this UNION suppose to run, there is an input for date range.